# How to extract and replace character back into a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the vowels from a text, reverse a list of these vowels, and insert them back in there original position. Here is a description of the problem:

Revorse the vewels def reverse_vowels(text): Given a text string, create and return a new string constructed by finding all its vowels and reversing their order, while keeping all other characters exactly as they were in their original positions. To make the result more presentable, the capitalization of each position must remain the same as it was in the original text. For example, reversing the vowels of 'Ilkka' should produce 'Alkki' instead of 'alkkI'. For this problem, vowels are the usual 'aeiouAEIOU'. Along with many possible ways to perform this dance, one straightforward way to reverse the vowels starts by appending the vowels of text into a separate list, and initializing the result to an empty string. Then, loop through all characters of the original text. Whenever the current character is a vowel, pop one from the end of the list of the vowels. Convert that vowel to either upper- or lowercase depending on the case of the vowel that was originally in that position, and add it to result. Otherwise, add the character from the original text to the result as it was.

Here is my code:

```
def reverse_vowels(text):
   vowels=['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
   lst=[i for i in text]
   new_list=[]
   new_word=""
   for i in text:
       if i in vowels:
           if i.isupper():
               lst.remove(i)
               new_list.append(i.lower())
           elif i.islower():
               lst.remove(i)
               new_list.append(i.upper())
   new_list=new_list[::-1]
   indexes = [index for index, element in enumerate(text) if element in vowels]
   for i in range(len(new_list)):
       lst.insert(indexes[i],new_list[i])
   return ''.join(lst)

text="""Who's the leader of the club
that's made for you and me? TR-
I-C-K-Y M-O-U-S-E! Tricky
Mouse! TRICKY MOUSE! Tricky
Mouse! TRICKY MOUSE! Forever
let us hold our Hammers high!
High! High! High!"""

expected_result="""Whi's thi liider af thu clob
thot's mude fer yeo end mu? TR-
O-C-K-Y M-I-E-S-U! Trocky
Miesu! TROCKY MIESU! Trocky
Miesu! TROCKY MIESA! Furovor
let as hald uer Hommers hagh!
Hegh! Hegh! Hogh!"""
```

If I do

```
print(reverse_vowels(text))
```

I get bad spelling:

```
WhI's thI lIIdEr Af thU clOb   
thOt's mUdE fEr yEO end mu? TR-
o-C-K-Y M-i-E-S-U! TrOcky      
MIesu! TRoCKY MiESU! TrOcky    
MIesu! TRoCKY MiESA! FUrOvOr   
lEt As hAld UEr HOmmErs hAgh!  
HEgh! HEgh! HOgh
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because "the code is not working" is in unacceptable problem description and there are no debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

Your code removes from the list of letters of your text in a weird way following the order of  `['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']` - not of the real occurences in your file.

IF you modify yours  to

> ```
> def reverse_vowels(text):
>    vowels=['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
>    lst=[i for i in text]
>    new_list=[]
>    new_word=""
>    print([a for a in  lst if a in vowels]) # correct order
>    for i in text:
>        if i in vowels:
>            if i.isupper():
>                lst.remove(i)
>                new_list.append(i.lower())
>            elif i.islower():
>                lst.remove(i)
>                new_list.append(i.upper())
>    new_list=new_list[::-1]
>    print(new_list)         # reversed upper/lower corrected order
> ```

You get

> ```
>  ['o', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'u', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'a', 'e', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'E', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'e', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'E', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'e', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'E', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'u', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'i', 'i']
>  ['I', 'I', 'I', 'I', 'E', 'A', 'U', 'O', 'O', 'U', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'O', 'e', 'u', 'o', 'i', 'E', 'U', 'O', 'I', 'e', 'u', 'o', 'i', 'E', 'U', 'O', 'I', 'e', 'u', 'o', 'i', 'E', 'A', 'U', 'O', 'O', 'E', 'A', 'A', 'U', 'E', 'O', 'E', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'O']
> ```

which is all wrong capitalisation-wise.

---

Your task has an exact algorythm to follow - why don't you?

```
text="""Who's the leader of the club
that's made for you and me? TR-
I-C-K-Y M-O-U-S-E! Tricky
Mouse! TRICKY MOUSE! Tricky
Mouse! TRICKY MOUSE! Forever
let us hold our Hammers high!
High! High! High!"""

expected="""Whi's thi liider af thu clob
thot's mude fer yeo end mu? TR-
O-C-K-Y M-I-E-S-U! Trocky
Miesu! TROCKY MIESU! Trocky
Miesu! TROCKY MIESA! Furovor
let as hald uer Hommers hagh!
Hegh! Hegh! Hogh!"""


# get all vowls from the text into a list
vowl = [a for a in text if a in "AEIOUaeiou"]
# or use a normal loop that goes through and adds each vowl into a list
# in order of occurence 

r = []
# go over the full text, 'c' is taking each letter of text
for c in text:
    # if c is a vowl 
    if c in "AEIOUaeiou":
        # pop from the list of vowls
        v = vowl.pop()
        # and fix spelling upper/lower
        r.append( v.upper() if c.isupper() else v.lower())
    else:
        # keep non vowls
        r.append(c)

result = ''.join(r)
print(result + "\n")
print("Same:", result == expected)
```

Output:

```
Whi's thi liider af thu clob
thot's mude fer yeo end mu? TR-
O-C-K-Y M-I-E-S-U! Trocky
Miesu! TROCKY MIESU! Trocky
Miesu! TROCKY MIESA! Furovor
let as hald uer Hommers hagh!
Hegh! Hegh! Hogh!

Same: True
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the new vowel needs to be upper or lower depending on the vowel it replaces.

Example (the "A will be upper since it replaces the "I" which is upper) :

```
text = "ab cdef ghIjk"
expected = "ib cdef ghAjk"
```

In your code, you don't use that information when you insert at the end.
My advice would be to do as follows :

- store vowels in the reversed list `new_list`
- go through each character of the text, and replace it by the corresponding character in `new_list` (in upper or lower according to the old character)

Here is an example of implementation :

```
def reverse_vowels(text):
    vowels=['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
    lst = list(text)
    new_list = [element for element in text if element in vowels][::-1]
    index = 0
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] in vowels:
            if lst[i].isupper():
                lst[i] = new_list[index].upper()
            elif lst[i].islower():
                lst[i] = new_list[index].lower()
            index += 1
    return ''.join(lst)
```

Comment: I did that the problem is that it can't handle large amounts of text

Comment: You didn't mention there was a problem with large amounts of text. Please try my solution and tell me